# Redux Is Not Updating React Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I hate asking this question again, but I just can't see where the problem is and I've studied the heck out of the other similar answers on this site. I tried to simplify this as much as possible just to see if I can get anything to work, but I'm still having the same problem. It isn't updating the component with the new state. I see the information logged in the console, but the component doesn't update with the new state...

```
prev state Object {myTest: Object}
index.js:168 action Object {type: "FETCH_MY_TEST_FULFILLED", payload: Array[4]}
index.js:176 next state Object {myTest: Object}
```

Here's the actions my-test-actions.js...

```
const myData = [
    {
        title: 'some title 1',
        content: 'some content 1'
    },
    {
        title: 'some title 2',
        content: 'some content 2'
    },
    {
        title: 'some title 3',
        content: 'some content 3'
    },
    {
        title: 'some title 4',
        content: 'some content 4'
    }
];

export function fetchMyTest() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_MY_TEST_FULFILLED", payload: myData});
    };
}
```

Here's the reducer my-test-reducer.js...

```
const actions = {
    FETCH_MY_TEST_FULFILLED: (state, {payload}) => {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            fetching: false,
            fetched: true,
            searchData: payload
        });
    }
};

const reducer = (state = {
    searchData: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null
}, action) => {
    return (actions[action.type]) ? actions[action.type](state, action) : state;
};

export default reducer;
```

Here's the component my-test.js...

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as myTestActions from '../actions/my-test-actions';

class MyTest extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMyTest();
    }

    renderSearchData(searchData) {
        let content = [];

        searchData.map((item, key) => {
            content.push(<div key={key}><h2>{item.title}</h2><p>{item.content}</p></div>);
        });

        return content;
    }

    render() {
        const {searchData} = this.props;

        console.log(this.props)

        return (
            <div className="my-test">
                {(searchData && searchData.length) ? this.renderSearchData(this.props.searchData) : 'No Data'}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MyTest.propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.string,
    fetchMyTest: PropTypes.func,
    fetching: PropTypes.bool,
    searchData: PropTypes.array
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        error: state.myTest.error,
        fetching: state.myTest.fetching,
        searchData: state.myTest.searchData
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(myTestActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyTest);
```

So the output I'm getting is "No data" because it appears that searchData isn't updated. Again, sorry for asking again and I have looked up the other answers, but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm missing or where I'm going wrong. I'm at a loss at this point.

Comment: You're dispatching an action with type `FETCH_MY_TEST_FULFILLED`, but your reducer only understands actions with type `FETCH_MY_TEST_FULLFILLED` (notice the extra L in `FULLFILLED`).  It looks like your reducer is just returning the state handed to it as a result.

Comment: OMG Michael. Thank you!!! I can't believe it was something that simple. Sadly I've been perplexed and working forever on this. Nice catch. I also noticed that I wasn't pulling the right part out of state in mapStateToProps. It should be state.myTest.searchData as opposed to state.searchData so I made edits to the above code so someone else might find it useful.

Comment: Lol, sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes :P  Glad you got it working!